# How to Override Any Key on X11

Tags: ubuntu, x11

> **Note**: This was [originally posted on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163179/how-to-override-any-key-on-ubuntu). However, since it got little traction, I chose to also post it here. I hope you don't mind it much. It's related to `X11` anyway, so I think it *will not be only* applicable to Ubuntu.

As far as I know, Ubuntu's Key Bindings are all exposed on the files inside the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` folder. I've sometimes used the `pc` file to make some changes to some keys. However, I would like to know if there is a *best practice* on how to override the keys, preferably without overwriting these core files.

For example, is there a way of creating a user keyboard setting that would override the default one (like most good code editors do nowadays, such as VS Code)? It would also be much better if this method used the terminal or saved the settings in a file, so I could easily reproduce it in other machines.

**EDIT:**

More specifically, right now, in my use case, I'm looking to customize my `FN` key.

Comment: The `Fn` key is frequently a special case, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495426/is-fn-key-not-defined-in-x-window-in-x11-keysymdef-h and can not be changed.

Comment: Ah, I see, more and more I feel like `X11` should receive a drastic upgrade: ["The X protocol has been at version 11 (hence "X11") since September 1987."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System)

Comment: The "upgrade" to X is called "Wayland"; the core X protocol won't get upgraded. But none of this affects your `Fn` key: The problem with this key is that your hardware doesn't report it normally; instead, it's handled by the *Embedded Controller* (EC) of your laptop, and each laptop does this differently. And the hardware manufacturers keep the details secret, and don't make drivers for Linux.

Comment: Really nasty workaround the manufacturers managed to pull off with the `Fn` key, wow. Personally, I think that users should be able to put a customized layer on everything the keyboard does... I think I'll move away from my current keyboard, which is one where they swapped the `Fn` key with the `Ctrl` key (Apple Style), something incredibly annoying.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Is this about remapping a key globally or in a specific application? If it's about remapping globally, whatever your question is, it's probably already been answered; search the [tag:keyboard-layout] tag. If it's about VScode, does that even run on Linux? And if it's about Fn, then as others have already said, software can't help you because it's handled in hardware.

Comment: If you want an expensive keyboard where you have complete control of everything then you may want to look at https://shop.keyboard.io  . Can you clarify if this keyboard is part of a laptop or is plugged into a computer, either via a serial connector or via usb?

Comment: @Gilles, Indeed vscode does run on linux, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

Comment: You can easily check by running the `xev` command, focusing its window, and then pressing the `FN` key, and noticing the keycode printed. Some `FN-other_key` combos may result in some keycode(s) that you may use (remap, etc). Notice that the xkb framework only handles the translation from keycodes to keysyms + modifier state -- any app still has access to the keycodes of any key/button pressed or released. The X11 protocol hardly stays in the way of anything.